BepInEx warning: "Found plugin with no attribute. Will be treated as non-compatible with vanilla." How to fix?
I was working on my first mod when I realized that the mod I was making wouldn't let me connect to vanilla servers. Each time I boot into Content Warning (a Mono compiled Unity game), I get this warning:
[Warning: Unity Log] Found plugin with no attribute. Will be treated as non-compatible with vanilla: PerformanceWarning.dll
How can I add an attribute to my plugin such that Unity will accept it as compatible with vanilla? I have no other plugins in my Plugins folder if that's important.
I am using the latest version of BepInEx (5.4.22), as well as Visual Studio 2022 to make the plugin. The game I am trying to mod is Content Warning, if that is important. I do not suspect that these are the reasons why my mod is being flagged by Unity to be incompatible with Vanilla, but rather some sort of missing attribute in an important file someplace.

What I was expecting: my mod to have run without Unity flagging it as incompatible with vanilla like all of the other mods out there.
I've tried peeking at the source code of other mods but to no avail as there seem to be no assembly attributes that I am missing, assembly attributes being the things that start with [assembly: in an AssemblyInfo.cs file.

Do you have the BepInPlugin attribute on your class?

If you are talking about [BepInPlugin(GUID, PLUGIN_NAME, PLUGIN_VERSION)] then yes I have that on my class.

After a few tries at examining source code of other plugins, I have found the solution to my problem, that I was missing a special plugin attribute that the game was looking for:
// the boolean is for whether or not the plugin is compatible with vanilla
[ContentWarningPlugin(MyGUID, PluginName, true)]

Regrettably, this is not information that can be applied to all cases where Unity regards a plugin as incompatible with vanilla versions of certain games, but in Content Warning, that is the case.
